# How can I compact my Scrap Mechanic logic down?

Tags: scrap-mechanic

Is there a way for me to more easily compact my logic? For example, Here I have this start to a 64bit ALU:
[image: start to a 64bit ALU]

I have no idea how I could just turn this into a 64-wide prism, but so often when you see complicated logic on the workshop, that is how it comes. A glass-enclosed cube.

How do people make these?

Note: If anyone reading this question knows a Scrap Mechanic logical engineer, share this question with them! Thank you.

Comment: I think that is either done with blueprint editing or just building it like that, and I don’t know how to edit blueprints.